# How Double.compare(a[0],b[0])) works?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to sort the 2D array

```
int[][] a1 = new int[][2];
```

and contents are

```
6, 8
5, 7
1, 3
2, 4
```

my expected output is :

```
1, 3
2, 4
5, 7
6, 8
```

I found that we can use Double.compare() method as,

```
Arrays.sort(a1,(a,b)->Double.compare(a[0],b[0]));
```

This did sort the array as I wanted, but I don't know how it is working?
can someone explain

Comment: [Arrays.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)) "Sorts the specified array of objects according to the order induced by the specified comparator."

Comment: Should be using `Integer.compare()` since you're comparing ints, not doubles...

Comment: You could also use `Comparator.comparingInt` like this: `Arrays.sort(a1, Comparator.comparingInt(arr -> arr[0]));`

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.sort(collection, oracle)` is the API you are using here. The collection is a list of (thingies), and the oracle is code (not a value, it's *code*, or at least, a value pointing at code). The oracle can decide which of 2 things is to be sorted 'before' the other.

Given an oracle that can tell you for any 2 (thingies) which one 'comes before', and a collection of (thingies), you can sort it efficiently. How? Well, various algorithms - point is, `Arrays.sort` is that algorithm and just like you can drive a car without knowing how a combustion engine works, you can use `Arrays.sort` without knowing those kinds of details. If you'd like to know - java's libraries are open source, you can have a look.

So, what's happening here?

Your list (`a1`) is a list of (thingies). (thingies) here is **int[]**. After all, you have an `int[][]`, and that is not a '2D int array' (that does not exist in java). It is an array of int arrays. (Which you can trivially use to emulate a 2D int array, so that's nice). So, When you try to pass a variable of type `int[][]` to `Arrays.sort`, you've handed an array of `int[]` (well, an array of them).

Thus, the oracle needs to decide which of 2 int arrays is 'earlier'.

And it does just that: The `(a, b)` are the 2 int arrays, and the code then decides which of those 2 is 'earlier' by looking at their first value (`a[0]` and `b[0]`) and then handing them to the `Double.compare` method which just.. compares 2 doubles the way you'd think (5 is 'before' 8.2, because, well, it is).

Why `Double`? No reason, no idea. `Integer` would make for more efficient and more readable code; all `int` can be converted to `double` without loss, so `Double.compare(someInt, someOtherInt)` always returns the exact same thing as `Integer.compare(someInt, someOtherInt)`. It's just less readable and less efficient.